# getEval threw an exception: missing ; before statement

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Selenium `getEval` throws error: `Error: getEval(${descr}): Threw an exception: missing ; before statement`

Code:

```
var soda = require('soda')
    , assert = require('assert');
var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
    , port: 4444
    , url: 'http://jquery.com'
    , browser: 'firefox'
});
browser.session(function(err){
    browser.open('/', function(err, body, res){
        browser.storeEval("window.jQuery('meta[name=description]').attr('content');", "descr", function(err, body, res){
            browser.getEval('${descr}',function(err,val){
                if(err !== null) throw err
                console.log(val)
                browser.testComplete(function(){ });
            });
        });
    });
})
```

Seemingly the problem is in my javascript expression: `window.jQuery('meta[name=description]').attr('content');`

...although it works in browser console.

And with another expression ...
`window.jQuery('.logo').height();`
... the same code working:

```
var soda = require('soda')
    , assert = require('assert');
var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
    , port: 4444
    , url: 'http://jquery.com'
    , browser: 'firefox'
});
browser.session(function(err){
    browser.open('/', function(err, body, res){
        browser.storeEval("window.jQuery('.logo').height();", "height", function(err, body, res){
            browser.getEval('${height}',function(err,val){
                if(err !== null) throw err
                console.log(val)
                browser.testComplete(function(){ });
            });
        });
    });
})
```